# RxSwift separate stream

Tags: swift, observable, rx-swift

Modified -----------------------------------------

there is a stream.

```
let o = Observable.just(1).concatMap(someProcedure).debug()
let o1 = o.map { "\($0 * 2)" }
let o2 = o.map { "\($0)" }
let proc = [o1, o2]
        
Observable.from(proc).concatMap { $0 }
    .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
            
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)

func someProcedure(_ value: Int) -> Observable<Int> {
    print("someProcedure!!")
        
    var result = 100
        
    // do something
       
    return Observable.just(result)
}
```

in this case, 'someProcedure!!' is printed twice.

i just want to use return value of func 'someProcedure' in two stream(o1, o2)

func 'someProcedure' is not need to execute twice .

is it possible?

Comment: _What_ do you want `o` to emit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Observable, it will create a *new* job for each subscription by default. This is why you are getting two procedures printed.

To fix this, you need to share the subscription...

```
let o = Observable.just(1).concatMap(someProcedure).debug()
    .share(replay: 1)
let o1 = o.map { "\($0 * 2)" }
let o2 = o.map { "\($0)" }
let proc = [o1, o2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `take(1)` operator on `o` to pass downstream only first emitted value